# Atmel and coil close on a board - is interference an issue?

Tags: atmel, interference, coil

I'm going to build a circuit which uses AVR uC (probably ATmega8 or some ATtiny) and a coil with iron powder ring core. The coil has 330uH and will be working under current of approx. 6A.

I'd like to make the PCB as compact as possible. Is there a danger that coil would interfere with uC? Yes, I'll be doing analog measurements with the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toroidal inductors tend to channel almost all if not all of the flux through the toroid material rather than through the surrounding air. This means that they can be placed very closely to other components (including digital ICs) while causing little to no interference. Having said that, you should still avoid routing analog connections under it, and observe proper decoupling measures.